# HTML unknown element, at least for me

Tags: javascript, html

I'm developing a data-recollection view in HTML and i've seen the need of creating something like this:

[image]

I explain, it's a shitty paint image, so, there is an input where user can introduce data and if he clicks the "+" button it will appear another one, just with the same mechanism.

Is there any element in HTML that makes that or should i create it on my own?

Edit:

I've been developing the form following an angular tutorial and I've got a problem.
This is what my view shows:

[image]

Below the label hijos, it should appear a button just like the one in dominio label. Don't have any idea of why is this happening. There is another problem also. The add button should add an input in case of dominio label and a select in case of hijos (if it was correctly showed). At the moment it does nothing. Here is the code I wrote.

HTML part:

```
<section name="nuevoMovimiento" class="row-fluid">
<form class="form-horizontal text-left">
    <fieldset>
        <div id="legend">
            <legend class="">New entry table</legend>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="id">Identificador:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="id" class="input" name="id" placeholder="Introduzca el ID" ng-model="controlET.nuevaTE.id">
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="desc">Descripción:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <textarea id="desc" name="desc" class="textarea" placeholder="Escriba una breve descripción" ng-model="controlET.nuevaTE.descripcion">                                   
                        </textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="tipo">Tipo:</label>
                    <select name="tipo" id="tipo" class="select" ng-options="" ng-model="controlET.nuevaTE.tipo"></select>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="tipo_vis">Tipo de visualización:</label>
                    <select name="tipo_vis" id="tipo_vis" class="select" ng-options="" ng-model="controlET.nuevaTE.tipo_visualizacion"></select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="visible">Visible</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="visible" id="visible" value="true" ng-model="controlET.nuevaTE.visible">Sí    
                    <input type="radio" name="visible" id="visible" value="false" ng-model="controlET.nuevaTE.visible">No
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="valor">Valor:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="valor" class="input" name="valor" placeholder="Introduzca el valor" ng-model="controlET.nuevaTE.valor">
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="enabled">Enabled:</label>
                    <input type="text" id="enabled" class="input" name="enabled" placeholder="Introduzca algo" ng-model="controlET.nuevaTE.enabled">
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="obligatorio">Obligatorio:</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="obligatorio" id="obligatorio" value="true" ng-model="controlET.nuevaTE.obligatorio">Sí    
                    <input type="radio" name="obligatorio" id="obligatorio" value="false" ng-model="controlET.nuevaTE.obligatorio">No
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="dominio">Dominio:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li ng-repeat="dominio in controlET.dominioRecollect">
                                <input type="text" ng-model="dominio.text">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form ng-submit="controlET.funciones.addDominio()">
                            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                    <label class="control-label" for="hijos">Hijos:</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <ul class="unstyled">
                            <li ng-repeat="hijos in controlET.hijosRecollect">
                                <select id="hijos" name="hijos" ng-options="te.id for te in controlET.TEs2" ng-model="hijos.id">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <form ng-submit="controlET.funciones.addDominio()">
                            <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="add">
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-centered">
            <button style="margin-top: 20px" type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="controlET.funciones.anadirTE()">
                <span>Guardar</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
</section>
```

JS part:

```
(function () {
var ControlETCtrl = function (ETFactory, $scope, $http, $window, $rootScope) {
    var scope = this;

    scope.titulo = "Entry tables list";

    scope.dominioRecollect = [];
    scope.hijosRecollect = [];

    scope.TEs = ETFactory.getTEs().success(function(data){
                                                scope.TEs = data;
                                                scope.TEs2 = data;
                                            });
    scope.TEs2 =[];
    scope.nuevaTE = {};

    scope.funciones = {};
    /*scope.funciones.cargarDatos = function () {
        console.log("Entra en cargarDatos()");
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            ETFactory.getTEs().success(function(data){
                                    scope.movimientos = data;
                               });
        });

    }*/
    scope.funciones.addDominio = function() {
        scope.dominioRecollect.push({});
    }
    scope.funciones.addHijo = function() {
        scope.hijosRecollect.push({});
    }
    scope.funciones.cambiarvalor = function () {
        ETFactory.cambiarvalor();
    }
    scope.funciones.anadirTE = function () {
        ETFactory.añadirNuevo(scope.nuevaTE);
    }
}
controlCajaApp.controller('ControlETCtrl', ['ETFactory', ControlETCtrl]);
}());
```

Well that's it, has somebody any idea?

Comment: "  it will appear another one...", another what? input? or another set of input-button. In any case, you'd have to use javascript.

Comment: https://angularjs.org/#add-some-control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's form submitting you're talking about, you might want to look into PHP.

However, if you're just going to be typing in stuff and not doing anything with the data, you can do something like this using jQuery: (http://jsfiddle.net/11x1gq3z/3/)

```
$(function() {
    var lolDiv = $('#inputs');
    var i = $('#inputs p').size() + 1;
    var addone = '<p><label for="inputs"><input type="text" id="input" size="20" name="input_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Another box" /></label> <a href="#" id="rembox">Remove</a></p>';

    $('#addbox').live('click', function() { //onclick of div "#addbox"
            $(addone).appendTo(lolDiv); //appends new box to lolDiv var
            i++; //counter
            return false;
    });

    $('#rembox').live('click', function() { 
            if( i > 2 ) {
                    $(this).parents('p').remove(); //removes <p> tags that the boxes are in
                    i--; //counter but minus this time
            }
            return false;
    });
});
```

Then for the HTML (Pretty basic):

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addbox">Add another box</a></h2>
<div id="inputs"><p>
<label for="inputs">
<input type="text" id="input" size="20" name="input" value="" placeholder="This is your box, yo" /></label>
</p></div>
```